# explain the inheritance in the code?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

there's this code :

```
class Base{
    public:
    void disp(){
    cout<<"base"<<endl;
    }
};

class Der1:public Base{
    public:
    void test1(){
    cout<<"der1 test1"<<endl;
    }
};

class Der2:public Base{
    public:
    void test2(){
    cout<<"der2 test2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Der3:public Der1,Der2{
    public:
    void fun(){
    cout<<"Der3 fun"<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Der3 d;
    d.test1();
}
```

OUTPUT: der1 test1  //printed successfully

but for

```
int main()
{
    Der3 d;
    d.test2();
}
```

it gives error that Der2 is inaccessible ...

*However when i change the code to*

```
class Base{
        public:
        void disp(){
        cout<<"base"<<endl;
        }
    };

class Der1:public Base{
    public:
    void test1(){
    cout<<"der1 test1"<<endl;
    }
};

class Der2:public Base{
    public:
    void test2(){
    cout<<"der2 test2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Der3:public Der2,Der1{  //***changed the order here*** 
    public:
    void fun(){
    cout<<"Der3 fun"<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Der3 d;
    d.test2();
}
```

it outputs: der2 Test2

Can someone explain what is happening here ?

Comment: I am going off of a whim here, but do you need to put the `public` keyword in front of BOTH parent classes? `class Der3:public Der2, public Der1` ?

Comment: i got the answer...sorry for posting ...how to delete the question ?

Comment: overlooked the second public keyword :/

Comment: Still a valid question, though, in my opinion

Comment: @guitar_geek : no point in deleting it.  Just mark an answer as correct (it could be one you write) and leave it for other having the same problem.

Comment: i have to wait 9 minutes to accept an answer,it seems, oh well. :P

Comment: Do you know that `Der3` inherits `Base` twice? The so called diamand problem. If you didn't mean to do so, you want ["virtual inheritance" for the `Base`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html).

Comment: @leemes..thanks for pointing that out .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
class Der3:public Der2, public Der1{
```

If you don't specify the access qualifier, it defaults to private.

Also because you have a common base in the two types inherited in Der3 you should use virtual inheritance in Der1 and Der2. This avoids replicating the common Base members (if any.)

```
class Der1:public virtual Base{...   
class Der2:public virtual Base{...
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the accessibility to *each* base class:

```
class Der3:public Der1, public Der2{
    public:
    void fun(){
    cout<<"Der3 fun"<<endl;
    }
};
```

When you switch the order `Der2` is a public base but `Der1` is private.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Der3:public Der1,Der2 {
```

The 'public' there is only good for the next base class.  You want to write:

```
class Der3: public Der1, public Der2 {
```

Also, it should be noted that this example also shows the deadly "diamond" inherience pattern,  so it's designer clearly should be slapped.

Answer (score 3):

By default, class inheritance is private. And so:

```
class Der3: public Der1, Der2
```

is the same as:

```
class Der3: public Der1, private Der2
```

You need to use public inheritance for both base classes:

```
class Der3: public Der1, public Der2
```